# Data retrieval and indexing

Tags: c++, opencv, kdtree, data-retrieval

I have around 800,000 rows of data stored in the boost shared memory from the database. The data are in the form:

```
Id        Color        Length          Size

1        1                 2            4
2        3                 4            5
3        2                 2            0
4        1                 2            4......and so on
```

The Colors can be the value from 1-12 the length 1-4 and the size 1-5,
The Id,Length,Color,Size are stored in seperate vector of 800,000 size in the shared memory. So there is Id vector for Id, Color vector for Color and so on.

I want to filter the data before I perform some computation. So I want data for which Color is 1 and length is 2 and Size 4 i.e row 1 and 4 in above case. Is there any efficient way to filter the data without using for loop and going through all the 800,000 images and checking the condition?

Right now I am just using mysql statement to get the Ids of the data which satisifies the condition.

```
"select Id from features_table where Color=1 and Length=2 and Size =4"
```

But is there a faster way to do this? Or should I stick to this method? I am looking for a faster method so I am not sure whether fetching the Ids from the database will increase the execution time of the algorithm.

What are the other options that I can consider in this case? I read about Hash table,B-Tree,Binary Search tree and I am confused which is suitable for this case. Will kd-tree be helpful in this case?Because many images may have the same combination of color,length and size. I am not sure if kd-tree is the right thing to do. I read about FLANN in opencv used for kd-tree is there any example or resources which may be helpful in this case? Or are there any built in c++ libraries?

Comment: Maybe consider tuning MySQL parameters. Are indexes being used? This query is an *exact match*, something that bitmap indexes should accelerate very well. If MySQL has support for such things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just doing this once.  If that is the case, then creating any data structure containing all of the elements is going to be slower than testing each element.  Make sure you move on to the next element after any on of them fails (in C/C++, an if statement with color==1 && length==2 && size==4 will automatically short circuit evaluate for you).  Read the data into a buffer, not one line or whatever at a time.  Loop towards zero and use pointers to avoid the implicit multiplication when resolving array indices.  Other than that, no optimizations come to mind.

Answer (score -1):

There is no faster way to filter the data other than going over each data item and checking it against the filter which is a complexity order of O(n). You have to access each item at least once. The same goes for building any kind of data structure from your data such as tree, hash table etc. If you are only interested in filtering the data once, just go over it and get the filtered list. If you need to perform other data manipulations, you should consider what actions you are going to need (insertion, deletion, sorting, etc.) and select the most efficient data structure according to your intended use.

Comment: really? -1? How is my answer not constructive?